# Arduino relay buzzing sound at higher voltages

Tags: arduino, relay

I have three arduino 4 channel relays connected to the three phases of mains supply. I am currently powering the Vcc of relays through an LM 7805 regulator which is taking input 12V and giving an output of 5V. I have also connected a 220V/12V 1Amp transformer to rectify my supply to 12V DC which is then fed to the LM 7805. On slowly increasing my input supply from 0-220V (Phase voltage) by an autotransformer, when I reach around 160V, the relay makes a buzzing sound (not the tick-tock sound which it makes when switching On and Off), and I have to immediately switch off my supply(afraid of blowing off the relay).

I have connected 22 microfarad and 1000 microfarad capacitors in the two ends of the LM 7805 respectively, for smoothing. Is the buzzing noise because the relay is staying put in On/Off condition, or is it something else?(I intend to use the relays in NC condition.)

Also, the R, Y, B phases of the main supply are connected to the three relays, and I have taken the rectifier's supply from the R phase, so, when I give Vcc to relays, the power contacts of the relays also get line voltage.

This is how I connected the regulator
[image]
This is my full circuit
[image]
(I have not shown the connections between the arduino and acs 712). 
Thanking in advance!

Comment: The schematic shows an LM317 instead of LM7805.
Not at all sure about the rectifer. The polarity looks wrong. I'd be surprised if the 7805 didn't release the ghost after that.
Also, you're showing one leg of the relay going down to the ground, while _nothing else_ on this side of the transformer does. This won't work.

Comment: Are you sure it's the relay making that noise, rather than the transformer? If it is the transformer, odds are the output is shorted via the 7805 (or 317 or whatever it is) connected backwards.

Comment: Where did the schematic go?

Comment: Schematic or it never happened.  Closing as unclear in the mean time.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am new to this site and trying to figure out the fratures. Have uploaded the schematic. Sorry for the hand drawn sketch, couldn't find an lm 7805 in proteus :(

Comment: The larger capacitor (1000 uF) should be on the input of the 7805, not on the output.

Comment: could you please explain the reason for the larger capacitor being on the input side?

Comment: Because that's where the rectifier ripple is. You're feeding the regulator with full-waved rectified DC with too little smoothing. You need to provide a full schematic and indicate which supply you are varying from 0 to 220 V. "*I have to immediately switch off my supply.*" Why?

Comment: What is your relay switching during this test?

Comment: "I have to immediately switch off my supply" because I am afraid the relay will blow off because of the buzzing. During this test, the relay is supposed to cut off the supply to the three phases when current in the line exceeds a threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference and to protect against edits, here is the schematic being discussed:

[image]

The major problem here is that there is not enough input voltage to the 7805.

The 12 V secondary is center-tapped, so puts out 6 V RMS on each end relative to the center.  That means the peaks are 8.5 V.  There is one diode drop in series, so the input of the 7805 sees peaks of about 7.8 V.

7.8 V is enough for the 7805 to produce regulated 5 V out, but just barely.  Since that's at the peaks only, the voltage out of the diodes will be lower most of the rest of the time.

What is happening is that as you slowly crank up the voltage, the peaks into the 7805 get just high enough for it to produce just enough voltage to trip the relays at those peaks, but not at other times.  That's why the relays buzz.  They are being driven at twice the power line frequency, because there are two peaks per cycle.  Turn the voltage up all the way.

However, even at full voltage you still have a problem.  22 µF to hold up the voltage between peaks is a joke.  1 mF on the output also doesn't make much sense since that only helps after the regulated voltage has already started sagging.

Flip the two caps around, assuming the 1 mF cap can handle the input voltage.  It should be rated for 10 V at least.  It would also help to change the diodes to Schottkys.  That would give you maybe another 300 mV, which you desperately need.

Let's see what kind of load this power supply can sustain with a 1 mF cap on the unregulated voltage and with Schottky diodes.  Let's say the peaks go as high as 8.1 V out of the diodes now.  You didn't say what your line frequency is, so I'll use 50 Hz in this example.  For simplicity, we'll say that the cap gets charged instantly every 10 ms.  Let's say the 7805 needs 7.5 V in to keep the output regulated.  That means the voltage on the cap can be allowed to drop 600 mV between peaks.  The maximum output current to stay in regulation is therefore (600 mV)(1 mF)/(10 ms) = 60 mA.

If all the relays you ever want to power at the same time require more than 60 mA total, then you need to re-think this power supply.  And, note that this is after the changes already described.

Answer (score 0):

As you increase the transformer's input voltage, its output voltage increases.

If the 7805 does not have sufficient input voltage, it cannot provide a 5 V output.

The output of the voltage-starved regulator will be oscillating at twice the mains frequency. The amplitude of the oscillation will decrease as the transformer output voltage increases to a continuously sufficient voltage for the 7805 to regulate its output.

If you feed an oscillating voltage above some threshold into a coil and that coil is attached to something that can move back and forth, say a relay mechanism, there will be a buzzing. With insufficient power, it won't be actuating the relay, just moving the parts a little bit.

Give it 220 V. The worst that is likely to happen is a bang!

P.S. Don't have the relay contacts connected to anything when you're testing at first - a three-phase whoops is not so much bang! as BANG!